# (Flutter/Dart) If Else Statement with List<String> Condition

Tags: flutter, dart

How could you help me?
How to make a condition, If Else statement with List <String'> Condition?
I have tried many things that probably could solved my trouble. But i still get stucked.

so, i want to make a condition when the List<String'> status = 'Available' it's color set to green, and when the List<String'> status = 'Not Available' it's color gonna set to red.

here's my code :

```
List<String> status = ['Available','Not Available','Available','Available','Not Available'];

_getMyColor(status){
   if(status == "Available"){
     return Color(0x00FF00);
   } else {
     return Color(0xFF0000);
   }
}
```

And then i call this function into my widget (of course with ListView.builder)

```
Text(status[index]), style: TextStyle(color: _getMyColor(status))
```

The code isn't got error message, but it makes my Text widget disappear.

I really appreciate any answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to fix the types in flutter so you may better change your code like this:

```
List<String> status = ['Available','Not Available','Available','Available','Not Available'];

Color _getMyColor(String status){
   if(status == "Available"){
     return Color(0x00FF00);
   } else {
     return Color(0xFF0000);
   }
}
```

and you can simply use this like this:

```
Text(status[index]), style: TextStyle(color: _getMyColor(status[index]))
```

Comment: that was so horrible, i'm wasting so many time to fix this things. And, now you save my day.. i really appreciate for your answer to help my troubleshoot. thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

For a better structure use enum:

```
enum MyStatus{
  available, notAvailable
}
```

then

```
  Color _getMyColor(MyStatus status){
    switch(status){
      case MyStatus.available:
        return const Color(0x0000ff00);
      case MyStatus.notAvailable:
        return const Color(0x00ff0000);
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your help. but it didn't save me. But, your suggestions are very nice

Answer (score 0):

Like Benyamin Beyzaie showed in his answer, you missed the list indexer, when calling _getMyColor

```
...(color: _getMyColor(status[index]))
```

Comment: yass.. that was so horrible. every little details is so important. thanks for your help